# How to check if empty string inside an object and set it into another object?

Tags: reactjs, mapping

I am making a re-useable drop menu component.

`const objectInfo = {firstName:"", lastName:"", age:""}`

`const objectError = { firstNameError: false, lastNameError: false, ageError: false, }`

And I am going to pass the objectError to the drop menu component to set the error to true if the related element is an empty string.

But the problem is I don't know the logic how to map through those elements and match them to the specific position.

Comment: Your question is not very clear, Though i guess you are thinking the 'React' way. Everything in React is a *reaction* to some event. Something like, when the user selects the drop drop down you can add and the element is empty, pass the objectError.

Comment: Yes, and there is a onClick button to handle the information to pass down by an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just loop through object keys

```
const objectError ={}
for(key in objectInfo){
   objectError[key] = !objectInfo[key]
}
```

Comment: Clever! Thank you ver much!